# AspNet Core Web Api console messages

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a NetCore WebApi solution. Some months ago it worked fine, but now when started from Visual Studio, after Chrome has opened in the console window there are repeated messages like those. To stop them I have to press ctrl-c

Solution is up to date
Thank you very much

```
Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest. Hosting environment: Development Content root path: D:\SwDev\PigstuffNg\backend\src\Common\Common.WebApiCore Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53367%2Fdevtools%2Fbrowser%2Fa8a34e84-74f7-4b32-b81e-67db169e0cb7 warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect. info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 170.2827ms 404 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53367%2Fdevtools%2Fbrowser%2Fa8a34e84-74f7-4b32-b81e-67db169e0cb7 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 3.5147ms 404 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53367%2Fdevtools%2Fbrowser%2Fa8a34e84-74f7-4b32-b81e-67db169e0cb7 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 8.7624ms 404 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser=ws%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53367%2Fdevtools%2Fbrowser%2Fa8a34e84-74f7-4b32-b81e-67db169e0cb7 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 2.702ms 404
```

Comment: Do you enable the https redirection in the startup.cs? It seems that you don't set the https port for your application but you have used https redirection. I suggest you could try to delete the https redirection codes and try again.

Comment: Hi Brando, htts redirecion was enabled but disable it not change the behaviour. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I did some try with blazor and I added to launsettings.json this line

```
"inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
```

After removing it the application starts normally.